# How to set Neovim as Unity's external editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, vim, text-editor, neovim

I'm looking to set my homebrew installed neovim as an external editor for Unity3D. The only way to set the external editor that I've seen is

> Preferences > External Editor > Browse

which opens up a finder window. Since my neovim install is in `/usr/local/Cellar/`, I'm unable to set this using the finder.

I've seen plenty of (now archived) posts on using vim or neovim with Unity but none on how to actually set it as the external editor. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!